# Android Target e o Android SDK não encontrado ou instalado... mas está tudo instalado, como resolver?

Tags: android, ionic, android-studio, apache-cordova

Tive que formatar meu PC, Windows, e instalei tudo novamente: Java, Git, Python, Android Studio, Node, Ionic 3, Cordova, tudo.  E estava rodando antes normal.

Agora estou com este erro, não conseguindo rodar minha aplicação Ionic 3 com Cordova e Android.

```
cordova requirements android

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

Mas meu ANDROID_HOME environment está correto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já baixei o Tools do site do Android Studio e coloqui na pasta. Fiz todas as recomendações que já vi na internet.

**Como pedido nos comentários, o print da pasta SDK:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver?

Comment: E tem como tirar um print do conteudo da pasta `Android/Sdk`?

Comment: Oi @GuilhermeNascimento editei com o print.

Comment: Não tem o `SDK Manager.exe` nem o `AVD Manager.exe`, não sei de onde vc obteve esse SDK, mas com certeza esta faltando coisa

Comment: Ramos, eu tive um problema parecido e resolvi usando o próprio android studio, não o uso para programar, mas uso ele para gerenciar o sdk e o avd. Tenta usando ele aí, qualquer coisa comenta que tentaremos ajudar!

Comment: @Ramos além de  `C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` coloque também o `C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` e `C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms` em seu ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo fortemente a utilização do Android Studio, por mais que você não vá desenvolver nele, ele é ótimo para dar manutenção no SDK. Além de na instalação resolver as variáveis de ambiente: [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz isso. Não deu certo.

Comment: Lá no seu android studio tem como você ver o caminho do android home, copie ele e rode o comando:

set ANDROID_HOME=C:\ installation location \android-sdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools